# Conditions in an if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm looking through this article (https://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/06/18/solving-sudoku-in-c-with-recursive-backtracking/) explaining a backtracking approach to solve a sudoku puzzle in C and I had a couple of questions about conditions in if statements.

He uses if(puzzle[row][column]), I am unsure as to what it is checking. If a number exists in that position it will continue? For this I would have thought to use != null to check that it's not empty

He also uses a function call inside an if statement: if(isValid(nextNum, puzzle, row, column) Does this mean if the function is successful it executes what's inside the if?

Comment: if `puzzle[row][column]` values 0 the condition is false, else it is true, it a short way to write `if (puzzle[row][column] != 0)`, not != null because it is an array of _int_ and null is 'reserved' for pointer

Comment: Example: `int apples = 42; if(apples) { /* will be executed */ }`. In the second question, `isValid()` returns a non-0 value for the expression to be `true`.

Comment: You need to include the code fragment (or preferably, a [mcve]) in the question.  As it is, it makes no sense at all if the linked resource is unavailable.  Please [edit] to make your question complete *in itself* (you can keep the link, but the question shouldn't *depend* on it to make sense).

Answer (score 3):

Because, in C `int` expressions can be used in place of boolean expressions with 0 being false and anything else being true, `if(puzzle[row][column])` is an idiomatic way of writing

```
if(puzzle[row][column] != 0)
```

I prefer the latter because the former does seem to confuse people not familiar with the idiom.

> If a number exists in that position it will continue? For this I would have thought to use != null

The values in a cell are number - `int`s in fact. He uses zero as a convention for "not filled in yet". If the values in the array were pointers, I would agree, with `if(puzzle[row][column] != NULL)` but they aren't pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In C conditionals 0 is false and anything non-zero is true.  `puzzle` is a 2-dimensional array of `int`.  If the `int` is 0 then the conditional evaluates as false.  If the `int` is non-zero then the conditional evaluates as true.